# Error estimate for quasi Monte-Carlo integration over general domain

Tags: integration, statistics, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

Does someone know where to look for such an estimate? I can only find quasi monte-carlo integration estimates for **cubical domains** based on Koksma-Hlawka inequality.

Comment: What kind of a domain are you thinking? Rectangular but elongated? Spherical? Infinite in some direction? Any shape?

Comment: A non-cubical convex and bounded domain for example.

Comment: You could just wrap your bounded domain inside a cube and multiply your integrand with the indicator function of your domain. I guess the estimates you get from this are not tight enough for you?

Comment: Interesting, would an indicator function for example be a smooth compactly supported function over the embedded domain? 
I am primarily interested in a decay rate w.r.t. N, not so much the constants. Do you perhaps have a reference?

Comment: I don't have a reference, it's just a suggestion off the top of my head. I was thinking of simply the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_B(x) = 1$ if $x \in B$, and zero otherwise. Not smooth at all but that should not prevent it from being in the integrand of QMC?

Comment: I see. For QMC one needs a bounded total variation, which, in the Lp spaces depends on the mixed derivative of the integrand.

Comment: I believe the few jump discontinuities from $\mathbf{1}$ (with $B$ convex!) would not ruin the bounded variation (but I'm not a lawyer so take my words with a grain of salt).